# How to create google workspace by API

Tags: google-api, google-workspace

I'm trying to create a google workspace with her API but I don't find any information about it.

I understand that I can manage my workspace with the admin sdk, but how to create a new workspace for a new domain

I can buy a domain by API but not subscribe to a workspace ?

The goal is to create custom email when buying a domain name programmaticaly

Comment: I seriously doubt there is an api that would let you programmatically create a new google workspace domain.   This is something that should be done via the web app.

Comment: Why it should only be done via the wep app ? Do you think that I can do it from an other way or it's impossible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Admin SDK Reseller API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/codelab/end-to-end) has a [`customers.insert` method](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/reference/rest/v1/customers/insert) that will create a new Google Workspace customer, from there you can add domain names and Workspace subscriptions, but you need to be an authorized reseller first (see [prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/how-tos/prerequisites)).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible but the goal behind was to handle different "group" that you can handle with Organisation.

Create different Google Workspace wasn't the real need.